# ionic platform add ios failed

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cross-platform

When I try to run

```
ionic platform add ios
```

it fails with following error:
`Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?`
Yes, I'm in an ionic project, called `todo`.
What do I do to fix this?

FYI, here is `ionic info` output:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.3.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

Comment: In this thread you can find a possible solution https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/couldnt-find-ionic-config-json-file-are-you-in-an-ionic-project/51214/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/couldnt-find-ionic-config-json-file-are-you-in-an-ionic-project/51214/6) in ionic forum.
I'm just leaving the summary of the solutions if anyone needs it:

#### Solution 1:

- Open a text editor.
- Write following lines:

  `{
    "name": "todo",
    "app_id": ""
  }`

  Note: `app_id`your ionic cloud id. If you don't have one, leave it as is.
- Save it as `ionic.config.json` in `todo` project directory.

#### Solution 2:

- move to parent directory using `cd ..`
- remove project directory using `rm -r todo/`. (caution: save your changes before removing).
- create new project using `ionic start todo blank` command.
- Restore your changes.

If the stated solutions don't work for you, uninstall and re-install ionic and Cordova/PhoneGap and try again.